# Ubuntu 20.04 i915 passthrough with libvirt/kvm

Tags: virtualization, intel-graphics, kvm-virtualization, intel-nuc, i915

I'm trying to passthrough my integrated Intel GPU for transcoding purposes.

### Host

I'm running on a NUC with a Coffee Lake i7 processor with ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz

```
$ uname -a
Linux black-nuc 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ virsh version
Compiled against library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using API: QEMU 6.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 4.2.0
```

I setup vfio and mdev support

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
vfio_virqfd
vfio_mdev
kvmgt
intel_agp
i915

$ cat /etc/default/grup | grep DEFAULT
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet i915.enable_gvt=1 i915.enable_guc=2 intel_iommu=on"
```

I think at the host level it's ok, though not really sure

```
$ dmesg | grep i915
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=a264d72d-88e2-4a8e-908e-13a93ffe8b3f ro quiet i915.enable_gvt=1 i915.enable_guc=2 intel_iommu=on
[    0.103360] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=a264d72d-88e2-4a8e-908e-13a93ffe8b3f ro quiet i915.enable_gvt=1 i915.enable_guc=2 intel_iommu=on
[    2.446932] i915 0000:00:02.0: Found 128MB of eDRAM
[    2.446954] i915 0000:00:02.0: VT-d active for gfx access
[    2.446956] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.447316] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/gvt/vid_0x8086_did_0x3ea5_rid_0x01.golden_hw_state failed with error -2
[    2.492613] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    2.493395] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    2.563336] i915 0000:00:02.0: GuC firmware i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin version 33.0 submission:disabled
[    2.563337] i915 0000:00:02.0: HuC firmware i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin version 2.0 authenticated:yes
[    2.565319] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    4.766021] i915 0000:00:02.0: MDEV: Registered
[    5.008090] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])

$ lsmod | grep i915
i915                 1986560  3 kvmgt
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
drm                   491520  4 drm_kms_helper,kvmgt,i915
video                  49152  1 i915

$ ls /sys/class/drm/
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-DP-2  card0-HDMI-A-1  renderD128  version
```

I can see the MDEV devices

```
$ ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/
i915-GVTg_V5_1  
i915-GVTg_V5_2  
i915-GVTg_V5_4  
i915-GVTg_V5_8
```

I registered a mdev with a uuid to pass it to the vm

```
$ echo "e08e572c-1b52-4f50-96e6-25f43d1f8d6e" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/create

$ ls /sys/bus/mdev/devices/e08e572c-1b52-4f50-96e6-25f43d1f8d6e/
driver  intel_vgpu  iommu_group  mdev_type  power  remove  subsystem  uevent
```

#### libvirt

I added the mdev device to my VM

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="mdev" managed="no" model="vfio-pci" display="off">
  <source>
    <address uuid="e08e572c-1b52-4f50-96e6-25f43d1f8d6e"/>
  </source>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x09" function="0x0"/>
</hostdev>
```

### Guest

I'm not really sure what I have to setup on the guest.

It's running Ubuntu 20.04 with this image https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img

```
$ uname -a
Linux k3s-2 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can see the device but not driver initialized

```
$ lspci -s 00:09.0 -k
00:09.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics 655 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics 655

$ lsmod | grep i915
(empty)

$ modinfo i915
modinfo: ERROR: Module i915 not found
```

I'm expecting to see some files on `/sys/class/drm` like the ones I see in the host but I only see the version file

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm
version
```

I tried clinfo to see if proper devices are detected

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong opencl-icd package for this hardware
(If you have multiple ICDs installed and OpenCL works, you can ignore this message)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform
```

Any help is very appreciated. I have read ton of stuff and understanding half of it, so maybe I'm mixing some stuff.

### I have also tried

- Set the mdev pci device in the VM at 0x02
- Add `vfio-pci.ids=8086:3ea5` to the kernel command, but that makes my mdev devices disappear

Comment: There was a new bit added to the [20.04 Ubuntu serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt) about passthrough, including vfio-pci. (about half way down the page).

Comment: Thanks @DougSmythies, I'll take a look

Comment: Didn't work. Same the guest shows the device, but no driver used..

Comment: Odd, the driver was loading for me in the same experiment. But you likely run `linux-kvm` in the guest, which lacks i915. Do you have i915 available at all: `$ modinfo i915`? Consider installing and rebooting into `linux-generic`. Can you try with some opencl load if you can work with the card at all? For transcoding that should be enough, if you need UI a thing to try is setting "display=on" in the guest definition, that would give it a second screen with the content of that card. If you connect to the guest with e.g. `virt-viewer` it will open multiple screens then.

Comment: I'm running this on the guest https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt If I run `$ modinfo i915` I get `modinfo: ERROR: Module i915 not found`. Also, running `clinfo` I get 0 devices... I updated the post with this info and the complete logs from clinfo. I think on the guest I'm on linux-generic... I updated the post with `uname -a` for the guest

Comment: On a cloud image (meant for virtual environments) you are on `linux-virtual` by default @JuanIgnacioDonoso. That is confirmed by the i915 being missing. Due to that you are missing `linux-modules-extra-` which would contain i915 and so many other drivers usually not needed in virt environments. Run `apt install linux-generic` (not even a reboot needed) and you should get to the next step.